# vb.net: Distinguish between me.close() and x-button

Tags: vb.net, forms, events, sender, formclosing

how is it possible to distinguish between the event, that the user explicitly pressed to x-button (or pressed ALT F4) to close a form and all other methodes of closing the form programatically (me.close(), etc).
I already figured out, that this could be done using sender objects but I don't really get it. Could somebody explain it for me with an example? 
Thank you all very much in advance.

Comment: Assuming you are using the `FormClosing` event, `sender` will always be the form itself since that is who sent/triggered the event.  The event args tell you the reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The class FormClosingEventArgs event args has an enumeration to tell what the reason the form is closing.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.closereason(v=vs.110).aspx

```
Private Sub Form1_FormClosing(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.Closing

    If Not appClosing AndAlso e.CloseReason = System.Windows.Forms.CloseReason.UserClosing Then

    ' DO WHATEVER CODE YOU WANT IN HERE
    ' LIKE SETTING E.CANCEL TO TRUE

    End If

End Sub

' You can also set a close appClosing local variable at the class level as a boolean, whenever you call closing in code, assign the variable.
appClosing = True
Me.Close();
```

Comment: Thanks Ctznkane, it tried exactly this and the problem is, that the if command executes when i send me.close() from the code as well. There seem to be to real Close.Reasons to distinguish me.close() and the x-button!?

Answer (score 2):

It's as simple as that. :)

```
Private Sub Form1_FormClosing(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As FormClosingEventArgs)
e.Cancel = True
End Sub
```

This will prevent the `X` button to close the form and also the :) .The issue is that if you do this you cannot close your form using `Me.Close` too , To fix this,just remove the `EventHandler` :)

```
  RemoveHandler Me.Closing, AddressOf Form1_FormClosing
  'Now close the form
  Me.Close()
```

Answer (score 0):

A form with ControlBox set to True (hence X button at top right corner).
A Close button that closes the form.

To differentiate, you need to know that there is a Button Property called DialogResult with default value DialogResult.None

```
Private Sub CloseButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CloseButton.Click

    DialogResult = DialogResult.OK

    ' Add other codes you wish here

End Sub ' End of CloseButton_Click


Private Sub MyFormClosing(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.FormClosing

    If DialogResult = DialogResult.OK Then

        ' Triggered by Close button

    Else

        ' Triggered by X button

    End If

End Sub ' End of MyFormClosing
```